# How do I stop people reading my iMessages as they come in?

Tags: iphone

I don't want anyone to be able to see from whom I am receiving iMessages or text messages or the content of those messages.

Can I hide both!?

Answer (score 15):

If you mean from the Lock Screen or Notifications Centre, then
Settings > Notifications > Messages
switch off Lock Screen &/or Notification Centre

.. or if you simply want the content of the messages disabled, lower down the screen [out of sight on this image] uncheck Show Previews - though that will show who sent a message, but not the content.

[image]

Comment: Unchecking *Show Previews* seems like what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Probably right - I'll promote it.